# What is the name of this design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

jQuery uses this pattern. Essentially it involves every method returning a reference to the same object on which the method was called.

```
myClassInstance
    .DoMethodA()
    .DoMethodB()
    .DoMethodC()
    .CleanUp();
```

What's this design pattern called?

**UPDATE**
The accepted answer is correct, and here is the link to the wikipedia entry for it - less informative than the link provided in the answer though :P
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Comment: btw it's an idiom, not a design pattern

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is called [method chaining](http://martinfowler.com/dslCatalog/methodChaining.html).

Answer (score 8):

[Fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)

Comment: Almost correct - turns out Fluent Interface is an application of method chaining, which is the correct answer. Thanks for the link though; great info there.

Answer (score 2):

its called a [Fluent Interface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html)

Answer (score -1):

It is called Builder pattern..